# How do relocation packages typically work?

Tags: relocation

I understand that relocation packages are offered for helping you to move from where you are and get situated to a new location, but how exactly do they work?

Is this something you just get a lump sum of money upon signing the contract? If it is, then how is it different than a signing bonus?

Or is relocation package something that strictly just covers for the expenses that occur while you move (E.G: gas, moving truck, hotels etc.)? I assume then you will be reimbursed the exact amount you spent after you've completed your move.

I'd like some clarification on this matter

Comment: The important distinction between a chunk of money for relocation & a simple signing bonus is how it's taxed.

Comment: One other distinction could be political. For instance, if your future coworkers hear that you got a large sign-on bonus that they didn't get themselves, they may be upset. But on the other hand, if they hear that you got a more generous relocation package, because you moved from far away and they didn't, then they wouldn't have grounds to complain.

Comment: This could be relevant: http://www.overseas-exile.com/2012/09/we-dont-pay-for-relocation.html - you might also want to look at [expats.se].

Comment: W.... wut? put on hold as off topic...?? I literally just wanted to know what "relocation package" is and how it differs from a signing bonus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very employer, position, and distance dependent.  Some level of itemization and/or approved expenses is likely; but what is covered can range from enough to rent a truck and buy beer and pizza for a few of your friends on the low end, up to a white glove service that covers everything up to and including packing all of your possessions for you.  Other perks can include millage on your car, a rental car, or airfare for one or more trips to and from your new location; along with temporary housing and money for meals while you look for a permanent home.

Comment: So for clarification, this is never something like "Here, we'll give you $1000 in cash just for moving from X to Y." right? Otherwise, that would be like a signing bonus, I imagine

Comment: @Xiagua anything is possible; but you're dead on about why doing it that was is unlikely.

Comment: It depends on the company. I would say that the more 'in demand' the position is, the more likely that the company would offer what some candidates would deem a 'better' relocation offer of a lump sum. I've personally received lump sums to move across the US, and have heard of a few others that were offered ~10k for moves internationally.

Comment: For example, if you had a high turnover rate and were frequently hiring new candidates, it would behoove you to itemize receipts for relocation claims, to ensure that you're only paying out what was actually incurred (For example, $750) instead of a flat $1000, in instances where a difference like that might have occurred.

Answer (score 1):

It could go many ways.

Some employers will reimburse you based on itemized receipts.

Others will offer you a lump sum.

In **either** situation, pay attention to the associated terms. Many will tie a sort of **'loyalty'** clause to relocation reimbursements such that if you are not employed with the company for X amount of time (for example, 18 months or 2 years), they may require you to **pay it back**. This can really bug you if you find that you're not happy with the company a few months down the road and will find it difficult to shoulder the burden of re-paying this relocation fee, if it's specified that you will have to do so.

In my own experience, I was offered (What I perceive to be a fairly low amount of) $2500 to move from Chicago to Phoenix.

I paid $1400 to cancel my lease early (2 months rent equivalent), and spent the rest of the money on driving down here with my things, among various other expenses. There was no 'Here's the receipt for the expenses I incurred.'

I'd say one of the most notable differences with this pay, compared to a sign on bonus, is that it's **taxed** differently.

When you file your taxes, you can deduct **moving expenses** in most situations (When you clearly needed to move for the new job). You'll then enter in the amounts you paid for various types of 'covered' moving expenses, and how much you were reimbursed. The difference is summed with your AGI; meaning a net positive (You profited from your move and moving expenses) may increase your AGI, as the difference is treated as **income**, while a net loss (you spent more money than you were reimbursed) may lower your adjusted gross income, and thus lower the amount of taxes you owed and increase your potential refund.

Additionally, note that relocation packages are a form of **compensation**, and you have the right to **negotiate**. If they give you a number that's low, just like with salary, it's in your best interest to counter with a more reasonable number and an explanation of why you feel that way.